# Generating Elliptic Curve Private Key in Python with the cryptography library

Tags: python, cryptography, elliptic-curve, python-cryptography

I am attempting to generate a public/private elliptic curve key pair in python using hazmat in cryptography. Below is the current code that I have. When I run, it is generating the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'generate_elliptic_curve_private_key'

```
ecurve = asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurve
ecurve.name = 'secp256r1'
ecurve.key_size = 128
ec_backend = cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces.EllipticCurveBackend.generate_elliptic_curve_private_key(cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces.EllipticCurveBackend, ecurve)
key = asymmetric.ec.generate_private_key(curve=ecurve, backend=ec_backend)
```

Here is the documentation https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#

Comment: `EllipticCurveBackend` ... The term "backend" here shouts "do not use" back at me. Even if it runs, it probably crashes on the first rewrite of the EC functionality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see where `generate_elliptic_curve_private_key` method is available.

Here is an example of generating a [`SECP256R1`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurveOID.SECP256R1) and serializing the public key into PEM format:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec

private_key = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP256R1(), default_backend())
public_key = private_key.public_key()
# serializing into PEM
rsa_pem = public_key.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM, format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
```

#### printing the key

```
In [14]: print(rsa_pem.decode())
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEilwhueTwySfEbXd9y/inZVsYVG6z
/UJyVbN+cYgtIFd0vLdaP27cME8RGE/enMEcX7/jkb13j2DPnXt2R6teZw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: This does answer the question, however, I was trying to set the size of the key in the original code. Is there any way to do this inside the above?

Comment: Key sizes are strictly tied to the curve parameters (e.g. a named curve like secp256r1). If you want a larger key size you need to use a different curve. secp256r1 has private keys that are 256-bit because the secret scalar (the private key) is a value less than the curve's order (which is 256-bit). The example provided here is the correct API for key generation (and public point serialization) on a given curve.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!